# openshift: mount directory is not getting populated with initial data from container

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin, openshift-3, openshift-enterprise, okd

My openshift template with pv,pvc and deployment config is as follows:

```
kind: Template
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: okd-static-server.
labels:
  template: okd-static-server

objects:
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: PersistentVolume
  metadata:
    name: okd-static-volume
  spec:
    storageClassName: manual
    capacity:
      storage: 1Gi
    persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
    accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
    nfs:
      path: /mnt/k8smount/static
      server: <nfs_server_ip>

- apiVersion: v1
  kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
  metadata:
    name: okd-static-volume
    creationTimestamp: null
  spec:
    storageClassName: manual
    accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
    resources:
      requests:
        storage: 1Gi
    volumeName: okd-static-volume


- apiVersion: v1
  kind: DeploymentConfig
  metadata:
    creationTimestamp: null
    generation: 2
    labels:
      app: okd-static-server
    name: okd-static-server
  spec:
    replicas: 1
    selector:
      app: okd-static-server
      deploymentconfig: okd-static-server
    strategy:
      type: Rolling
    template:
      metadata:
        creationTimestamp: null
        labels:
          app: okd-static-server
          deploymentconfig: okd-static-server
      spec:
        containers:
        - image: okd-static-server:dev1.0.0
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          name: okd-static-server
          resources: {}
          volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /usr/share/nginx
            name: okd-static
        restartPolicy: Always

        volumes:
        - name: okd-static
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: okd-static-volume-claim
```

The image `okd-static-server:dev1.0.0` which is used above in the deployment config is built using the following dockerfile

```
FROM nginx:1.16-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /var/run/nginx /var/log/nginx /var/cache/nginx && \
    chown -R nginx:0 /var/run/nginx /var/log/nginx /var/cache/nginx && \
    chmod -R g=u /var/run/nginx /var/log/nginx /var/cache/nginx

ADD static/ /usr/share/nginx

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

ENV PATH /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

USER nginx:nginx
EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["nginx","-g","daemon off;"]
```

As mentioned in the above dockerfile, during the docker image build the static content is copied to the folder `/usr/share/nginx` of the image.
The image folder: `/usr/share/nginx` is mounted to the nfs mount directory `/mnt/k8smount/static` which could be observed from the openshift template above.

Initally the nfs mount directory will be empty. The issue here im facing is once the built image is deployed using the above openshift template, the nfs mount directory is not having the expected static contents. Instead it is empty.

Note: Manually adding content to nfs mount directory will populate the content to container folder: `/usr/share/nginx`.

Openshift/okd version: 3.11

Answer (score 0):

When you build the docker image, the ADD command gets executed and data is copied to `/usr/share/nginx` folder. At this point, the image does not have any information that you intend this to be a mount point to NFS. You cannot copy data from a static folder to a volume through `ADD` command in the dockerfile.

You could have the static data available in your container on a local folder.